# Difference between mutex lock and pthread_join

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

What's the difference between the two?

Aren't they the same thing in that they both wait for a thread to finish before executing another thread?

I'm trying to understand the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *functionC();
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int  counter = 0;

main()
{
    int rc1, rc2;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

 /*Create independent threads each of which will execute functionC */

     if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
   }

   if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionC, NULL)) )
   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
   }

   /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
   /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
   /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   exit(0);
}    
void *functionC()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
   counter++;
   printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: They're not particularly similar. It's a bit like asking what's the difference between an apple and supply-side economics.

Answer (score 11):

They're not actually the same thing.

A mutex (mutual exclusion semaphore) is a means to restrict the use of a resource to one thread at a time (with both threads obviously capable of running). When a thread returns successfully from a `pthread_mutex_lock` call, it is guaranteed to be the only thread holding that lock. Any thread that tries to lock that mutex after that point will generally have to wait until the owning thread unlocks it.

In other words, the thread with the lock is the only thread capable of manipulating the resource protected by that lock (assuming, of course, that other threads don't touch the resource without first acquiring the lock - you have to play by the rules).

A `pthread_join`, on the other hand, allows a thread to wait for another thread to *exit.* This is often used in the main thread to wait for all child threads to exit (there are other uses, that's just a typical one). A successful return from `pthread_join` means that the other thread is no longer running.

In the code you've shown, two threads are running concurrently and both the `counter` increment and the call to `printf` are protected by `mutex1`. The `pthread_join` calls at the end of `main` will make the main thread wait until your two child threads exit before continuing.

As an aside, you should check the return values from `pthread_mutex_lock` since it *can* fail. You don't want to go ahead and modify the protected resource in that case as corruption may occur. Ditto for `pthread_join`.

And, for a more comprehensive test, the following function would be better:

```
void *functionC() {
    int i;
    for (i = 1000; i > 0; i--) {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex1);
        counter++;
        printf ("Counter value: %d\n", counter);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);
    }
}
```

since it will more likely have the threads running side-by-side. Without the loop, there's a good chance one thread will exit before the second even starts.

Comment: ^ by resource you mean like a variable being using by that thread?

Comment: @Ted, that's one example. But a mutex can be used to protect variables, prevent code from running in two threads simultaneously, stop output to the terminal from being intermixed by multiple threads and many other things.

Comment: Unless an implementation defines extra error conditions for `pthread_mutex_lock` or you're using a special mutex type (like error-checking or robust), there's no way `pthread_mutex_lock` can fail. And if it failed on an implementation-specific error, I'm not sure how you could handle this anyway. I think it's very reasonable not to check the return value except when using robust mutexes.

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_join()` waits for a thread to exit.  A mutex_lock acquires control of a semaphore which prevents cooperating threads from simultaneously accessing the protected resource.