# i wanna know what's the diffrent between mutex_lock and pthread_join?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, pthread-join

What's the difference between `mutex_lock` and `pthread_join` in these two source codes? They seem both to do the same thing, making the main function wait for the thread to finish execution.

This code:

```
#include "philo.h"

typedef struct s_bablo
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} t_bablo;

void *myturn(void *arg)
{
    t_bablo *bablo = (t_bablo *)arg;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        printf("My Turn ! %d\n", i);
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bablo->mutex);
}

void *yourturn()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        printf("Your Turn ! %d\n", i);
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    t_bablo bablo;
    pthread_mutex_init(&bablo.mutex, NULL);
    pthread_t ph;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bablo.mutex);
    pthread_create(&ph, NULL, myturn, &bablo);
    yourturn();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bablo.mutex);

}
```

And this code :

```
#include "philo.h"

void *myturn(void *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        printf("My Turn ! %d\n", i);
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void *yourturn()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        printf("Your Turn ! %d\n", i);
        i++;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t ph;
    pthread_create(&ph, NULL, myturn, NULL);
    yourturn();
    pthread_join(ph, NULL);

}
```

Comment: Hello
Please edit your code to make it readable.

Comment: Does this [Difference between mutex lock and pthread_join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053421/difference-between-mutex-lock-and-pthread-join) answer your question?

Comment: They're totally different. One waits for a lock to be cleared, the other waits for a thread to finish.

Comment: They would only be equivalent if the thread locks the mutex for the entire time that it's running.

Comment: @Barmar, no, cause `join` will actually free the thread resources.

Comment: The mutex-based version has undefined behavior because it relies on a different thread to unlock the mutex than the one that locked it.  You could do that with a semaphore, but not with a mutex.

Comment: @Barmar, no, they would not be equivalent in that case.  The program would then deadlock because the main thread locks the mutex before starting the second thread.  And if the main thread did not do that then program behavior would depend on which thread managed to lock the mutex first -- if the main thread, which would be possible in principle, then the program would terminate before the other acquired the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

not to be rude but you can easily find the difference by googling both functions name...

Though `pthread_mutex_lock` is for variables. It locks this variable for the current running thread. Thus no other thread can use it, they have to wait for `pthread_mutex_unlock` to use it.

`pthread_join` waits for the specified thread to finish it's execution before continuing

I encourage you to read the man pages, they are really self explanatory.